# Decomposition of a Hölder continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a bounded, Hölder continuous function. Let $0<r<s$. How is it possible to write $f=f_1+f_2$ with $f_1$ Hölder continuous  and vanishing outside $B_s(0)$ and $f_2$ vanishing inside $B_r(0)$.

I was thinking $f_1(x)=f(x)$ for $x\in B_r(0)$ and $f_1(x)=d(x,B_s(0)^c)d(s,r)^{-1} f(x)$ (with $d$ as the distance). But I couldn't quite prove it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you know that there are smooth partitions of unity?

Comment: Is it possible without?

Answer (score 1):

A Lipschitz partition of unity suffices for this, and it is quite close to what you had in mind. Namely, introduce the functions
$$
\phi_1(x) = \frac{d(x, B_s(0)^c)}{d(x, B_r(0))+d(x, B_s(0)^c)},
\quad \phi_2(x) = \frac{d(x, B_r(0))}{d(x, B_r(0))+d(x, B_s(0)^c)}
$$
Note that on $B_r(0)$ and on $B_s(0)^c$ these functions are constant. 
In between, each numerator is $1$-Lipschitz and bounded above by $s-r$, while the denominator is $2$-Lipschitz, and is bounded below by $s-r$.

Therefore, $\phi_1,\phi_2$ are Lipschitz with constant $L=3/(s-r)$: the easiest way to check this is by using the quotient rule to bound the gradient, but you can also argue directly, as in the proof that the quotient of continuous functions is continuous.

Then, $f_1=f\phi_1$ and $f_2=f\phi_2$ satisfy the required conditions.